# How to find the location of file under a directory tree?

Tags: macos, appkit, foundation

Given a filename, say **foo.txt** and a base directory URL, say **~/bar/directory** what's the best way to find the subdirectory for the first occurrence of the file?

- Is there an existing API in Foundation or AppKit?
- Is, for example, a breadth-first search through the subtree the way to go? How would that look?
- Another way?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manually enumerate the directories:

```
func manualSearchFile(withName name: String, in path: String) {

    func search(url: URL) {
        do {
            let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.nameKey, .pathKey, .isDirectoryKey], options: [])
            try contents.forEach {
                let metadata = try $0.resourceValues(forKeys: [.nameKey, .pathKey, .isDirectoryKey])
                if metadata.name == name {
                    print("Manual Found: \(metadata.path ?? "unknown path")")
                }
                if metadata.isDirectory == true {
                    search(url: $0)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    search(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
}
manualSearchFile(withName: "foo.txt", in: "/bar/directory")
```

Another option is to use Spotlight, which is faster but only works for paths that are indexed. Many system directories are excluded and users can exclude even more in System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy.

```
var metadataQuery: NSMetadataQuery?
func spotlightSearchFile(withName name: String, in path: String) {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: nil, queue: nil) {

        guard let query = $0.object as? NSMetadataQuery else { return }
        query.enumerateResults { (result, index, cancel) in

            let item = result as? NSMetadataItem
            let path = item?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemPathKey) as? String
            print("Spotlight Found: \(path ?? "unknown path")")
        }
    }

    metadataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
    metadataQuery?.searchScopes = [path]
    metadataQuery?.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K like[cd] %@", NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey, name)
    metadataQuery?.start()
}
spotlightSearchFile(withName: "foo.txt", in: "/bar/directory")
```

For more information about the query syntax see the [Comparison of NSPredicate and Spotlight Query Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSpotlightComparison.html).

In the old days we used to have more options with `FSCatalogSearch` and `FSGetCatalogInfoBulk`. But these are no longer available, AFAIK.

Comment: That is a DFS solution right? i.e. will traverse directories down to their leaves first rather than searching across all the contents of a directory before continuing with subdirectories. Isn't what the `NSFileManager.enumerate` function provides too? I'm more interesting in a BFS with a preference to match files rather than directories.

Comment: I am not certain but - having seen it run hundred of times - linux ‘find’ looks BFS